# Merge addition of URL rewriting of sub-domain and single page to capture all URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have presently setup .htaccess according to the answer given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/45552/how-do-i-make-all-urls-run-through-a-single-php-file) to capture all URLs in a single file. Now I want to capture all URLs having no "www" subdomain and redirect to www.my-site.com.
So, presently I have (to capture all URLs in a single file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And I want to merge the following with it (capture all URLs having no "www" subdomain and redirect to www.my-site.com):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the redirection, and after the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```